# Update HTML meta tags inside index.html dynamically in Flutter Web

Tags: html, flutter, seo, flutter-web

I have created a website in Flutter web and added all meta tags inside index.html for SEO. The title tags get updated using the Flutter Title widget but I want to update description, keywords, og:title, og:description etc HTML tags for SEO when the webpage changes. How can I do this?

Comment: also wondering this too

Comment: looking for an answer as well

Comment: Also have this issue

Comment: Did you try this: https://almog.io/blog/dynamic-open-graph-meta-tags-flutter-web

Answer (score 0):

to append meta in header try this in main and before runApp

```
  html.MetaElement meta = html.MetaElement();
  meta.content = "meta-content";
  meta.name = "meta-name";
  html.document.head?.append(meta);
```

and don't forget to add to pubspec.yaml file in dependencies

```
http: ^0.13.4
```

and finally inspect your page to see it , it will be found before closing tag of header ,
also you can append any script or element to head or body tag

Comment: where to find the html object?

Comment: ```import 'dart:html' as html;```  
@RafsanUddinBegRizan

Answer (score 0):

Add to your pubspec.yaml:

```
dependencies:
  meta_seo: ^3.0.5
```

then add the meta method.